# Resources not responding in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm calling several resources in my Angular App like so:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll', 'chieffancypants.loadingBar', 'ngResource'])
```

And then in the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/loading-bar.js"></script>
```

But then, both the loading bar and the infinite scroll don't seem to respond.

Am I missing something?

Here's a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0aYg1TbnRFwW1WhuPKYp?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directives.js is redefining the myApp module when I think you mean to add to the existing module.

```
angular.module('myApp') // call without second parameter to retrieve the existing module
```